# Standalone application inside tomcat

Tags: java, multithreading, tomcat, web-applications

I have a simple java class that i want to run programmatically. This is basically a video player. It is also deployed along with my web application in tomcat. This should run upon a click on a particular link. From controller, here's how I run it

> new Thread(() -> {
>               VideoPlayer.main(new String[]{});
>           }).start();

It is working fine. But every time I close the Video player, tomcat is also terminated. Any ideas on how to correct this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your GUI probably calls `System.exit` when you close it. That'll take-down Tomcat since they are both running in the same JVM. Find and remove the `System.exit` and you'll find things work-out better for you.

Also note that it doesn't make any sense for a web application to launch a video player. Think about it: once the web application is no longer running on your own personal development workstation, the video will be played *on the server* where there isn't anyone to watch it. The server probably won't even have a monitor attached to it. Most likely, you'll get a whole series of exceptions from the video player telling you it couldn't initialize itself because there isn't any graphics environment in which to start.

Comment: You are right! When I removed this line of code videoPanel.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE) tomcat is  no longer terminated upon closing the player. However, this player is still running in background. Is there a way to kill this process programatically?

Comment: Also, I know that this is very ugly approach. I can't think of any solution wherein I can play a live feed from IP camera in a web application embedded in javafx webview. WebView doesn't support plugins and applets. Here's a SO question I've posted with some details of the project http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41262445/embed-ip-camera-feed-on-web-page-and-javafx-webview you might want to checkand give me ideas as well. Thank you very much :)

Comment: To kill the media player, you have to shut-down all the various threads. It's virtually impossible to shut-down the GUI thread (which is not a daemon thread) and, if you were to start it, you might not get it started back up again. The best strategy would be to launch an entirely new process, and then go ahead and use `EXIT_ON_CLOSE`.